# T-SQL query for Customers that ordered every product - how?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I have a *CustomerID* table, a *ProductID* table and an Orders table that lists every INDIVIDUAL (that is only one *ProductID* per record) that Customers ordered (quantity is not relevant).
Is there a way **using JOIN** to list Customers that have ordered each and every product in the past?
In other words all *customerID*s that have associated orders in Orders table for every *productID*...

I can do it with some intermediate/temp tables but I am curious if there is a way to use JOIN for that.

Thank you.

Cris

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select custID 
(
   select distinct custID, prodID 
   from order
)  orderD 
group by custID 
having count(*) = ( select count(*) from products )
```

Comment: This looks to do the trick, I was, for a reason, fixated on JOIN when there was a much simpler way when thinking outside the JOIN square. Thank you!

Comment: You can click the check if that was the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM User
WHERE 
  (SELECT DISTINCT (ProductId) FROM <order items of User>)
  = (SELECT count(*) FROM product)
```

More intuitive (probably):

```
SELECT 
FROM USER
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  from product 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM <order items of User and product>))
```